# 64bit SQL Server with total virtual address space of 4GB. How could this be?

Tags: sql-server-2012

My SQL Server 2012 Standard edition, 64bit has a total virtual address space of 4GB. Why is that?

**it is a 64bit installation: print @@VERSION :**

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (Intel X86) 
    Dec 28 2012 19:06:41 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (WOW64)
```

**virtual space of just 4GB**

```
select total_virtual_address_space_kb from sys.dm_os_process_memory 
4194176
```

(entire result of sys.dm_os_process_memory 
http://screencast.com/t/2PN2PDQYpt )

Comment: "Intel X86" - you installed the 32-bit version?

Comment: thanks @Phil I JUST freaking noticed that! I read the wrong article that said - x64 means its 64bit !

Comment: I think I win a prize.

Comment: This is a freaking nightmare that cost me days of stupid investigation! @Phil, can you shed some light on this related question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55030/how-to-move-from-32bit-sql-server-install-to-64bit

Comment: I don't know enough about SQL Server to help you - others will be along soon; I'm an Oracle DBA. I do, however, know my X86 from my X64 :P

Comment: he he, you're just showing off :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is because it isn't a 64-bit installation.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (**Intel X86**)

Intel X86 is 32-bit. X64 is 64-bit.

Answer (score -1):

Simple mistake of installing the 32-bit version instead of the 64-bit version.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (Intel X86) 
Dec 28 2012 19:06:41 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (WOW64)
```

This means 32-bit version, which has the stated memory limit. You should perform backups and reinstall SQL Server using the correct 64-bit version.