# How to move from 32bit SQL Server install to 64bit?

Tags: sql-server-2012, installation

A production server has accidentally been installed with SQL Server 2012 32bit version, while it needed a 64bit version.

How best to fix this issue?

Is it possible to simply UPGRADE from 32 to 64 bit version?

Should I just install a new instance of 64 bit version of SQL Server 2012 and then simply restore the backups?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in BOL [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades?view=sql-server-ver16):

> Cross-platform upgrade is not supported. You cannot upgrade a 32-bit instance of SQL Server to native 64-bit using SQL Server Setup. However, you can back up or detach databases from a 32-bit instance of SQL Server, and then restore or attach them to a new instance of SQL Server (64-bit) if the databases are not published in replication. You must re-create any logins and other user objects in master, msdb, and model system databases.

If you have installed a default instance of SQL Server and wish to keep it that way your only option is to remove the current install and install using the 64-bit media. Otherwise you can install a 64-bit instance as a named instance on the same server.

Cindy Gross has some additional useful information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cindygross/x64-windows-upgrade-from-32bit-sql-server-to-64bit-sql-server).

Comment: thanks Shawn! question - I seem to recall that named instances were problematic... not sure if I am going to get my self into trouble by installing named instance

Comment: Not sure what you mean by problematic, I support many servers that have named instances running.

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup all databases
2. Remove SQL Server 32-bit
3. Reinstall SQL Server 64-bit
4. Restore all databases

Comment: This is the correct process to go from 32bit to 64bit SQL installs, since cross-platform upgrades are not supported (as stated in the accepted answer by @ShawnMelton). I don't know why you were downvoted.